# Get an item of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function, who works fine, but when success i get data, and this data is an array.

```
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
}
```

this data return :

```
{"idResultat":172825,"idClientCat":1,"idClientLegende":"Tiers L\u00e9gitime","couleurCat":"#0062bd","couleurText":"#FFF"}
```

But when i try to get for example 'couleurCat', i have undefined.
I have try like this :

```
data['couleurCat']
data.couleurCat
```

but always undefined

Comment: what does ```typeof``` return for ```data```?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tiyedozedi/1/edit?js,console — It works fine when I test it. Try providing a real [mcve] instead of fragments of disconnected code.

Comment: Looks like `data` is a string, convert it to an object  before retrieving.

Comment: Could you post a larger example of what you are doing? I suspect you are accessing data before it is available.

Comment: Console.log doesn't always log the object as it is at the moment of the log. try logging Object.keys(data) to see which keys are defined at that moment

Comment: typeof data return me a string... i think thats why that fail ? In my function i return an array so i don't understand why i have a strign now.
Koby Douek found a solution : JSON.parse(data).couleurCat that works nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure your string as JSON before you can access elements. To access the JSON object in JavaScript, parse it with `JSON.parse()`, and access it via `.` or `[]`.

In your case, try using:

```
 JSON.parse(data).couleurCat;
```

Comment: I suspect that this is the right answer, but it needs expanding. I don't know why it's been downvoted.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser Added some explenations.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser Don't know why the downvote too... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

.Try to parse the string `JSON.parse(data)` and try to access it.

**code**

```
 data= JSON.parse(data)
 data['couleurCat']
```

Answer (score 0):

You said "`but when success i get data, and this data is an array.`" So you should be trying

`data[0].couleurCat`

You will have to specify the index of array then access the property.

Comment: I think he is not getting an array.